# IOS UITableViewCell content don't display completely or don't display

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

When I set the red part on the top cell ,the content of next part which is the green part doesn't display completely or doesn't display.Only when I select the green part ,the image will appear .If I put the one cell of green above the red part ,it will display and the next part which is under the red part doesn't appear.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        static NSString *identifyCell = @"TopCell";
        TopTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifyCell];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = (TopTableViewCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TopTableViewCell"
                                                                       owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            //cell.lbValue.hidden = YES;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }
        //config the cell
        return cell;
    }
    else{
        static NSString *identifyCell = @"HomeCell";
        HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifyCell];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = (HomeTableViewCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HomeTableViewCell"
                                                                       owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
             cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            //cell.lbValue.hidden = YES;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
        }
        cell.homeimg.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home1.jpg"];
        //config the cell
        return cell;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to post more information, are you using IB for tableview,  show us your code how you are creating your cells, are you using auto-layout? This is not enough to help you.

Comment: check your tableview co-ordinates

Comment: the height of cell is enough.the cell using xib.i don't use auto-layout

Comment: tableview co-ordinates is right and if i remove the cell of section 0,the next will display well.